# importing library js into a script and making available outside of the script

Tags: javascript, module

I have a project set up using Laravel 10 that in turn uses vite. I'm having a problem understanding the best approach to scripts for pages and importing js libraries such as moment or dayjs.

After installing through npm I have updated my `app.js` to import the library:

```
import './bootstrap';
import 'laravel-datatables-vite';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
import focus from '@alpinejs/focus';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.plugin(focus);

Alpine.start();
```

app.js is loaded via the page. However when I try and access `dayjs` from within a script tag within the page I get an error: dayjs is not defined.

This then means that the import is not being made available to scripts outside of app.js I think. In which case how best do I ensure dayjs is available outside of the module?

I have tried adding `window.dayjs = dayjs`; but that fails if I try to use it in the script for example:

```
const date = new Date();
console.log(dayjs(date, 'd/m/Y'));
```

which comes up with an error `dayjs is not defined`

If I use `windows.dayjs()`  I get an error that `dayjs` is not a function.

I can see dayjs is attached to the window object when I inspect with Chrome

Not sure of the correct way to resolve

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:
As Laravel load app.js defer, you can't reach the dayjs inline at normal mode.

You can use window.onload or if you would like to use blocking inline script, use **type="module"**

Example:

```
<script type="module">
dayjs()
</script>
```

Or:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
dayjs()
}
</script>
```

I am not sure, but if it is not working, try to add
`window.dayjs = dayjs;` to app.js!

Here is my full app.js regarding to dayjs:

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";

import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc'
import updateLocale from 'dayjs/plugin/updateLocale'
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone'
import duration from 'dayjs/plugin/duration'
import customParseFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat'
import relativeTime from 'dayjs/plugin/relativeTime'
import LocaleData from 'dayjs/plugin/LocaleData'

import 'dayjs/locale/hu'

dayjs.extend(utc)
dayjs.extend(updateLocale)
dayjs.extend(timezone)
dayjs.extend(duration)
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat)
dayjs.extend(relativeTime)
dayjs.extend(LocaleData)

window.dayjs = dayjs;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).